# send_file() when called return text document instead of an image

Tags: python, web, flask

I want to send an image file from server side to client side. I am using flask framework.

But the problem is whenever I call the route in which `send_file()` is, the response return is an File. When I click this file `gedit` opens it with nothing in that file. That means it must be text file written.

I referred the flask docs for [`send_file()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_file).

Here is what I am doing in the code:

```
@app.route('/try')
def trial():
    todown = 'https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net//hphotos-ak-xaf1//t51.2885-15//e35//12093691_1082288621781484_1524190206_n.jpg'  
    resp = requests.get(todown)
    return send_file(resp,mimetype="image/jpeg",attachment_filename="img.jpg",as_attachment=True)
```

Whenever I load `localhost:5000/try` a file is downloaded but not the image file that I want to download.

Error I am getting in my terminal is `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read' error`.

What must be the problem. Is anything missing in this above snippet?

Comment: Didn't you get `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'` error?

Comment: Do you need to be using `send_file(resp.content...)`?

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie If I use `resp.content` same thing happens

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. `resp` is a `requests.models.Response` object, not string nor bytes:

   ```
   >>> import requests
   >>> todown = 'https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net//hphotos-ak-xaf1//t51.2885-15//e35//12093691_1082288621781484_1524190206_n.jpg'
   >>> resp = requests.get(todown)
   >>> resp
   <Response [200]>
   >>> type(resp)
   <class 'requests.models.Response'>
   ```
2. `Flask.send_file()` *sends a file*.

---

So first at all you need use `resp.content` to get the content of the object, it'll return bytes object (and by the way, `resp.text` return string object.
Always use `.content` if you're downloading an image, video, or other non-text things).

```
>>> import requests
>>> todown = 'https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net//hphotos-ak-xaf1//t51.2885-15//e35//12093691_1082288621781484_1524190206_n.jpg'
>>> resp = requests.get(todown)
>>> type(resp.content)
<class 'bytes'>
```

Please check [the document](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for more details.

---

Then, because `Flask.send_file()` *send a file*, so you need write the image into a file before you send it.

But since you don't need use this image on your server anyway, I'd suggest use [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) in this case, then you don't need delete that image after you sent it. And note that use [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) if you're sending a text file.

For example:

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from flask import Flask, send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def tria():
    todown = 'https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net//hphotos-ak-xaf1//t51.2885-15//e35//12093691_1082288621781484_1524190206_n.jpg'
    resp = requests.get(todown)
    return send_file(BytesIO(resp.content), mimetype="image/jpeg", attachment_filename="img2.jpg", as_attachment=True)

app.run(port=80, debug=True)
```

---

However, if you want write the image into a file and send it then, sure you can also do it. We can use [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) to create a *tempfile* instead of just create a file to avoid rewrite your important files.

From the document:

> This function operates exactly as `TemporaryFile()` does, except that the file is guaranteed to have a visible name in the file system (on Unix, the directory entry is not unlinked).
>
> That name can be retrieved from the `name` attribute of the file object. Whether the name can be used to open the file a second time, while the named temporary file is still open, varies across platforms (it can be so used on Unix; it cannot on Windows NT or later). If delete is true (the default), the file is deleted as soon as it is closed.
>
> The returned object is always a file-like object whose `file` attribute is the underlying true file object. This file-like object can be used in a `with` statement, just like a normal file.

For example:

```
import tempfile
import requests
from flask import Flask, send_file

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def tria():
    todown = 'https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net//hphotos-ak-xaf1//t51.2885-15//e35//12093691_1082288621781484_1524190206_n.jpg'

    resp = requests.get(todown)

    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:  
        # create a file-like object use `NamedTemporaryFile()` and `with` 
        # as the basic usage which said in the document     

        f.write(resp.content)
        # write the content of the image into it

        return send_file(f.name, mimetype="image/jpeg",
                         attachment_filename="img2.jpg", as_attachment=True)                             
        # `f.name` is the temp file's filename

app.run(port=80, debug=True)
```

Comment: You explained me Like Iam5 . Very Good explanation. Thanks you

Comment: @SurajPalwe: No problem, glad I could help :)

Comment: I'd change the order of the two solutions. Writing the image to a file first (you'd need to delete it at some point too..) is rarely a good idea, and **especially** not with a hardcoded filename instead of file created by the `tempfile` module. That's just asking for trouble with more than one request at a time.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Yeah that's a good idea. Was want to show how does `send_file()` work. But sure, put the **correct** answer before a **demo for OP to understand how does it work** is a good idea. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Better, but I'd use this for the file instead of a hash: https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Huh, I never used it. Let me take a look at the document and try to edit my answer and use it.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Edited my answer again. Spent 10 mins to learn and test, and it's so useful! Is `io.BytesIO` still better than `NamedTemporaryFile()` in this case?

Comment: Yes, avoiding disk IO always makes sense, especially for something as small as the typical image file. If you wanted to serve it many times it would be a different thing, but then you would be using something more persistent anyway...

Comment: Good one! I had to add `f.seek(0)` after `f.write()` to get it working.